# Why was the Russian Federation Military expenditure cut in 1998-1999?

Tags: military, russia

I am looking into the Military Expenditure Data provided by SIPRI.

Interestingly through 1998-1999 Russian Federation's Military Expenditure was cut down to 14,000 almost half of 1997 which was 23,540 (million dollars, 2015 constant).

What happened?

Comment: the financial crisis of 1998 happened https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_Russian_financial_crisis

Comment: 14.000 is not less than half of 23.540...

Comment: Activity in the Chechen war subsided at that point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Chechen_War

Answer (score 1):

In 1998, the "twin deficits" in Russia (trade and budget) forced the country to [default on its debt.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_Russian_financial_crisis) Two other results were a devaluation of the ruble of approximately 35%, and a 5% *negative* GDP growth.

Assuming that defense expenditures remained constant in rubles, a 35% devaiuation against the dollar would have reduced defense spending from $23,500 millions to $15,500 millions. The 5% contraction in the economy would have taken the amount down further to $14,500 millions. These two effects explain nearly all of the drop to $14,000 millions.

Comment: Seems like the 35% devaluation of the Ruble could have done the job all on its own, considering the poster's numbers were in **dollars**.

Comment: @T.E.D.: True, fair enough. But the 5% GDP decline was almost certainly a contributing factor.